# Blazor Webassembly Load failed - Something with Dotnet sdk

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, sdk, blazor

So my project doesn't load (unloaded/load failed).

[image]

I get this message in my output window:

```
C:\Users\username\source\repos\MyProject\MyProject.csproj : error  : The project file cannot be opened. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET Core SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.
```

I have the newest Version of VS2019:

[image]

I allowed the use of previews of the .NET Core SDK

[image]

SDK 3.1.403 is installed.

[image]

My Project has no global.json. I tried to create global.json in my root folder.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.403"
  }
}
```

but it also did not work.

I downloaded and installed both .NET Core SDK x64 and x86.

My .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I restarted VS2019 and my Device everytime I changed anything.

Please help. I'm desperate. How can I work on this Solution?

Comment: How does `csproj` look like?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I edited my post. You can see my .csproj now

Comment: `net5.0` means .NET 5, which has the SDK _5.0.100-rc.2_ latest versio now. Why are you checking .NET Core 3.1 SDK?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't exactly understand what Visual Studio 2019 wants from me. I just want to load my project. I don't know why it mentions .net core 3.1 in the output window

Comment: There is nothing related to visual studio in your question, it shows an error form the latest installed available sdk. To build a project targeting `.net5.0` you have to download and install [.NET 5 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0). All packages in project also has `5.0.0-rc.2` version

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I downloaded and installed .NET 5 SDK. I get the same errors as before.

Comment: maybe because of the earlier created global.json? Navigate to the folder of your project in CLI and run `dotnet --version`. This will show you what SDK will be used for any dotnet core commands in that folder or subfolders.

Comment: @ZsoltBendes 5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15 is the output. Currently I have no global.json in my project folder

Comment: You could also try to create a build from CLI. Tooling for Blazor WASM is still work in progress. (sometimes closing VS helps).  `dotnet build` to create a build.

Comment: @ZsoltBendes Building was successful. Sadly the loading still fails.

Comment: Only 2 things I can think of. One is that you are using rc sdk with not the rc version of VS. The other one is that your solution file (not the project file) is corrupted. Try to remove the project from the solution and re add it. Could be some path settings are wrong in the sln file.

Comment: @ZsoltBendes Thank you very much. I installed VS Preview (I assumed this is the rc version). I was able open my project :)